# Populating an Array in VBA from different parts of a spreadsheet

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to populate different portions of an array based on different locations within a spreadsheet.

For example

```
Dim prices(50) as double

prices(0, 1, 2) = Range("i35", "i38")
prices(3,4,5,6,7,8) = Range("b7","b12")
```

I'm getting a wrong number of dimensions error, because I'm assuming you have to populate the whole thing at once. Is there another syntax to do this better, or is it just a limitation of VBA?

Possibly a for each loop? But that doesn't really help since there are a lot of different ranges.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? , maybe we can help you better that way, and you are right , you cant populate arrays like that

Comment: @Wabonano I just have a lot of prices for different securities in odd parts of a spreadsheet. I'm feeding them into an optimization algorithm, but that's not really relevant. I guess the options are to reformat the sheet, or just write out the code. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: See [Sample Visual Basic macros for working with arrays in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213798). It might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to tell VBA that the list of numbers in the parenthesis of the array are positions within an array that will receive multiple items.

That's not what it is. Instead, you can only do one at a time. For example:

```
Dim prices(50) as double
' My range syntax might be wrong here. 
prices(0) = Range("i35", "i35")
prices(1) = Range("i36", "i36")
prices(2) = Range("i37", "i37")
prices(3) = Range("i38", "i38")
```

..etc. Or, if you're new to programming, you'll find this really cool:

```
for CounterVariable = 0 to 3
   prices(CounterVariable) = Range("i" & 35 + CounterVariable)
next CounterVariable
```

To Wit ...

- an array defined like `Dim prices(50)` will have one 'dimension', like a straight line.
- Picture one row in a spreadsheet, 50 columns long.
- If you said `Dim prices(50,60)` you would have a 2-dimensional array, like a cartesian plane (x,y) or a 50x60 cell spreadsheet where the first number is like the letters, the second, like the numbered rows.
- Some languages support 3-dimensional arrays - VariableName(x,y,z). Don't know if VBA does
- Therefore, using commas in parenthesis after an array *is* supported by VBA
  **BUT** it means something completely different than you were hoping (and you can't change that): the values for the dimensions.
- So your last line of code is looking for some value in a 6-dimensional universe! So we've got, height, width, depth, time, tesseract, and uh, you've beat me there!!!